# Web page generator like LaTeX

Tags: html, latex, webpage, markup

forgive if this is dumb. I was wondering if there was any such thing like LaTeX, by which you could write in a markup and compile it to a whole web page (of course with CSS and other styling). I've heard of lightweight markup languages like Textile. But I don't think they serve my purpose.

Comment: html???? ()()())()(

Comment: You sound savvy enough to understand that HTML is a markup language.  Are you looking for something simpler (or possibly just something more LaTeX-like) that you can use to END UP with HTML rather than actually writing the HTML? The question as it stands is nonsensical.

Answer (score 3):

[TeX4ht](http://www.tug.org/applications/tex4ht/mn.html) would allow you to use LaTeX source directly to produce HTML webpages; it typically produces multiple files from a single .tex source. I think of it as a conversion tool, but it could be used directly for creation.

But I have to agree that your question is a little odd. HTML is itself a mark-up language, not terribly different from LaTeX; it would help to know exactly what you're after if it's not just that.

I would advise against using WYSIWYG HTML editors. All the ones I've tried are terrible. And if you're already used to editing LaTeX, learning to mark-up things up directly in HTML won't be a difficult transition.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is not to keep the information using two languages.
Webpages are written in HTML, which can be edited as a full language of its own.

It's best to start with a free HTML WYSIWYG Editor.

The most powerful of then is [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/index.html). It started life as a Java Editor but with recent releases has developed into a powerful text editor for web scripting.

If that's too technical to begin with, use [KompoZer](http://kompozer.net/), designed for non-technical computer users who want to create an attractive web site without needing to know HTML.

Another advanced editor is [HTML-Kit](http://www.htmlkit.com/), which began as a specialized HTML editor but now has so many plugins that it is a highly customizable and extensible development environment.

There are also quite a few commercial HTML WYSIWYG Editors.

Answer (score 0):

For what you're looking to do, Template Toolkit (TT; http://template-toolkit.org/) might be a good option.  It's a templating language that, among other things, will allow you to insert common HTML or CSS code into multiple pages just by linking to a file containing that code.  Here's an example from their About page:

```
[% INCLUDE header title="My First Example" %]
<p>
  Hello World!
</p>
[% INCLUDE footer copyright="2007 Arthur Dent" %]
```

It can do much more than this, too.  This other example from their website shows how TT can be usedis similar to LaTeX's citation syntax:

```
[% person = { 
     name    = 'Tom'
     email   = 'tom@tt2.org'
   }
%]
[% person.name  %]          # Tom
[% person.email %]          # tom@tt2.org
```

[Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit) is a free and open-source web language editor that has syntax colouring for Template Toolkit.  I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Markdown (the language used on this site can be converted to HTML. You can find out a lot about its syntax [on their website](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/).

Comment: Please add more information, like example usage. Markdown might be good.

Comment: Markdown is the same language that you use to type these comments. You could use [github page generator](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-as-a-static-site-generator-with-github-pages/) to generate HTML pages from things formatted in this way